# Lebesgue measurable $\sigma$-algebra isometry invariant

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $T_i:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined for $i=1,2,3$ as follows:

$$T_1(x)=x+\beta\\
T_2(x)=-x\\
T_3(x)=|\alpha|\;x\\
\text{where}\;\ \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R\text{ and}\; \alpha\ne0$$

I want to prove that:
$$T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)=\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*,\;\ i=1,2,3$$

I've already proved that $\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*\subset T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*),\;\ i=1,2,3$

 So It's left to prove that $T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)\subset \mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$, but I don't know how. What I've got is this:

Let $B\in T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)\Rightarrow\ \exists\ E\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$ s.t. $B=T_i(E)$ and also I've already proved that:

$$\lambda^*(T_i(E))=\lambda^*(E)\;\forall E\subset\Bbb R\;\ \text{for}\ i=1,2\\
\text{and}\;\ \lambda^*(T_3(E))=|\alpha|\lambda^*(E)\;\forall E\subset\Bbb R$$

So for i=1,2 I would get that $\lambda^*(B)=\lambda^*(T_i(E))=\lambda^*(E)=\overline{\lambda}(E)$

And that $\lambda^*(B)=\lambda^*(T_3(E))=|\alpha|\lambda^*(E)=|\alpha|\overline{\lambda}(E)$ 

Does the fact that $\lambda^*(B)=\overline{\lambda}(E)$ implies that B should be Lebesgue measurable and thus $B\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$ straightforward?

What do you think or suggest?

Answer (score 0):

All your transformations are invertible. If a set is the preimage of another set, it is also the image of one.

Comment: Ok, but how does this help?

Comment: I got it:

So, if $H_i$ are the inverse functions of $T_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, respectively, then:
$$\text{Let}\; B\in T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)\Rightarrow\ \exists\ E\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*\;\text{s.t.}\; B=T_i(E)$$

But, since $H_i$ is the inverse function for $i=1,2,3$ it's clear that $H_i(B)=E$ and $H_i^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$ since $H_i$ is Lebesgue measurable for $i=1,2,3$. But $H_i^{-1}(E)=H_i^{-1}(H_i(B))=B$ so $B\in\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$ and thus $T_i(\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)\subset \mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*$